# Rotate an array from center position

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to rotate an array from the center position. Say for example:

For an array `[1,2,3,4,5]` if I select `5` as the current element, the new array should be `[3,4,5,1,2]`. If I select `4`, it should be `[2,3,4,5,1]`

I tried the below code and it works for some extent but it positions the selected at the beginning instead of center.

Any help with the approach will be really appreciated

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4];
function rot(arr, ind)
{
    var narr = [];
        var len = arr.length;
        for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        {
            narr.push((i+ind<len?arr[i+ind]:arr[len-i-1]));
        }
    return narr;
}
console.log(rot(arr,0))
```

Comment: Why `2` occurs twice in 2nd output?

Comment: What if there is an even number of items in the array?

Comment: The second argument is index or value?

Comment: @VDWWD my requirement is only for odd number of items

Comment: @NathanXabedi its the value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
let rot= (a,v,i=a.indexOf(v)) => a.map((x,j)=> a[(i+1+j+a.length/2)%a.length|0])
```

where `n|0` cast float to integer. We use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let arr=[1,2,3,4,5];

let rot=(a,v,i=a.indexOf(v))=>a.map((x,j)=>a[(i+1+j+a.length/2)%a.length|0]);
 
console.log( rot(arr,4) ); 
console.log( rot(arr,5) );
```

Comment: Should not it be `a.map(/* ... */)` instead of `arr.map(/* ... */)`?

Answer (score 2):

First, find how much you are going rotate the array (`delta`) then you splice as much items as its magnitude from the front if it is negative or the back if it is positive.
Put the spliced items on the opposite end.

```js
function rot(arr, center) {
  const index = arr.indexOf(center)
  if (index === -1) {
    throw new Error('')
  }
  if (arr.length % 2 === 0) {
    throw new Error('')
  }
  const cIndex = Math.floor(arr.length/2)
  const delta = cIndex - index
  let narr = [...arr]
  if (delta > 0) {
    let temp = narr.splice(-delta)
    narr = [...temp, ...narr]
  }
  else if (delta < 0) {
    let temp = narr.splice(0, -delta)
    narr = [...narr, ...temp]
  }
  return narr
}

let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(rot(arr, 1))
console.log(rot(arr, 2))
console.log(rot(arr, 3))
console.log(rot(arr, 4))
console.log(rot(arr, 5))
```

Answer (score 2):

this is basically the same as what @Mohammad posted, but instead of using ind as the index, you use arr.indexOf(ind) to get the relevant index.

I'd also add something to deal with the case you can't find the value...

```js
let arrr = [1,2,3,4,5];
function rot(arr, ind) {
    let narr = [...arr]; //copy and de-reference our array
    let indexFound = narr.indexOf(ind); //find out where ind is
    if(indexFound < 0 ) return narr; //ind was not found in your array
    let len = Math.floor((narr.length/2) - indexFound); //find out how far your target is from the center
    let doShift  = (len < 0); //if len is negative, then we need elements from the beginning moved, otherwise move the elements off the end with pop()
    len = Math.abs(len); //make sure len is always positive so our loop can run
   for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
      if(doShift) narr.push(narr.shift());
        else narr.unshift(narr.pop());
    }
    return narr;
}

console.log(rot(arrr,3));
console.log(rot(arrr,1));
console.log(rot(arrr,5));
```

Edit: modified to handle shifting from the end or beginning